# Dynamic domain URL Rest factory AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want change dynamic REST URL (for example if is stage or production) with a simple change in a server, but the URL don't change:

I have tried this:

```
.factory('Auth', ['$resource', 'Config', function($resource, Config) { 
    var URL = function(){
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        window.localStorage.setItem("REST", "http://dynamic"+random+".com/");  
        return window.localStorage.getItem("REST");
    }
    return $resource(_url, {url:"url"}, {
        login: { method:'POST', url:  URL()},
    })
}])
```

And this

```
   // Generate random URL in the controller
   .factory('Auth', ['$resource', 'Config', function($resource, Config) { 
        var URL = window.localStorage.getItem("REST");
        return $resource(_url, {url:"url"}, {
            login: { method:'POST', url:  URL},
        })
    }])
```

But when I change the url ( I check this url in local storage and its change) the domain is the same anywhere unless that I reload the page, in this case works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

Add a 2 new constant:

```
  .constant('HOST_CDN', {
    development: {
      api: 'http://YOUR_LOCAL_DOMAIN',
    },
    production: {
      api: 'http://YOUR_PRODUCTION_DOMAIN',
    }
  })
  .constant('ENV', 'development')
```

Create new service:

```
var domain = null;

(function getDomains() {
  domain = HOST_CDN[ENV];

  if (!domain) {
    throw 'Could not get domains';
  }

  domain.api   = domain.api.concat('/')
                           .replace(/\/\/$/, '/');
})();

return {
  api   : domain.api
};
```

Comment: The problem is that URL doesn't change, unless you refresh your browser (WebView).

Comment: You can use my sample code and add a localStorage to set/get this URL.